# Selenium throws stale error , how to solve?

Tags: python, selenium

Whenever i run this , it throws the given error. I tried making a list to append but cant solve.

```
 link_div = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[id='sidebar1269']")[0]
            all_divs  = link_div.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='v1269 hidepiece']")


            alls = []
            for div in all_divs:
                ALL = div.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
                alls.append(ALL[2])

            print(alls)
```

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0):

Google is your Friend :-) Second result when searching for "Selenium stale error":

> A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases:
>
> The element that we are trying to interact
>   1. has been deleted entirely
>   2. no longer attached to the DOM

http://allselenium.info/handle-stale-element-reference-exception-python-selenium/

So, the elements you try to handle are no longer available.